# Atmega32 UART: проблема с посылкой данных

Tags: avr, uart

Пытаюсь приконнектить Atmega32 по UART к компьютеру. По какой-то причине данные посылаются только из цикла for(;;){}. Если попробовать отправить данные все цикла или по прерыванию - не получается.

Код:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#define FOSC 16000000

#define USART_BAUDRATE 9600   
#define BAUD_PRESCALE (((FOSC / (USART_BAUDRATE * 16UL))) - 1)

volatile unsigned char value;  

void USART_init(){
   UBRRL = BAUD_PRESCALE;
   UBRRH = (BAUD_PRESCALE >> 8); 
   // Enable receiver and transmitter and receive complete interrupt 
   UCSRB = ((1<<TXEN)|(1<<RXEN) | (1<<RXCIE));
}

char String[]="Hello world!!";
char String_1[]="UUUUUUU";

unsigned char USART_Receive() {
    while( !(UCSRA & (1<<RXC)) );
    return UDR;
}

void USART_Transmit(unsigned char data) {
    while( !( UCSRA & (1<<UDRE)) );
    UDR = data;
}

void USART_putstring(char* StringPtr){
     while(*StringPtr != 0x00){
     USART_Transmit(*StringPtr);
        StringPtr++;
     }
}
int main(void){
    USART_init();

    _delay_ms(5000);
    USART_putstring(String_1); // здесь не работает

    for(;;) { // отсылается только это
       _delay_ms(5000);
       USART_putstring(String);
    }  
 }
```

Comment: а если убрать первый USART_putstring и в цикле делать только одну итерацию, будет что-нибудь приходить?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan если сделать цикл на одну или какое-то определенное количество итераций, тоже не отправляет.

Comment: не должно быть связано, константу в `FOSC` стоит как UL объявить.

Comment: не хватает настройки стоп битов/размера символов в UCSRC, в принципе в этом может быть дело...